# fetch returns 400 when posting to localhost

Tags: javascript, fetch-api

I wish to do the following in javascript:

```
curl --data "client_id=admin-cli&username=xx&password=xx&grant_type=password" http://localhost:8082/auth/realms/mine/protocol/openid-connect/token
```

And here is my attempt:

```
    const data = {"client_id":"admin-cli","username":"xx","password":"xx,"grant_type":"password"};
    const formData = new FormData();
    for(name in data) {
        formData.append(name, data[name]);
    }
    fetch("http://localhost:8082/auth/realms/mine/protocol/openid-connect/token", {
        method: "POST",
        body: formData
    })
        .then(function (response) {
            return response.text();
        })
        .then(function (text) {
            console.log('Request successful', text.length,text);
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            console.log('Request failed', error)
        });
```

Which produces the error:

```
POST http://localhost:8082/auth/realms/mine/protocol/openid-connect/token 400 (Bad Request)
localhost/:1 Fetch API cannot load http://localhost:8082/auth/realms/mine/protocol/openid-connect/token. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:18080' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 400. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
bundle.js:24428 Request failed TypeError: Failed to fetch
```

What am I doing wrong? I am doing a proof of concept so I will be happy with any solution as long as it returns me the token.

I have also tried:

```
fetch("http://localhost:8082/auth/realms/mine/protocol/openid-connect/token?client_id=admin-cli&username=sa&password=sa&grant_type=password", {
            method: "POST"
        })
```

with the same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`-d`/`--data`](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html#-d) option for `curl` sends requests with `Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded` and with the data formatted just like a query string, as a single string with the parameters separated by `&` and the values preceded by `=`.

So to emulate that, you'd need to do:

```
fetch("http://localhost:8082/auth/realms/mine/protocol/openid-connect/token", {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {  
      "Content-type":
      "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8"  
    },  
    body:
      "client_id=admin-cli&username=xx&password=xx&grant_type=password"
})
```

[FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/FormData) formats its data as `multipart/form-data`, which is not what you want if your aim is to replicate that `curl` call.

Answer (score 1):

Body attribute uses json string kindly can you please try following
Also note that Get and Head HTTP requests can not have bodies.

```
fetch("http://localhost:8082/auth/realms/mine/protocol/openid-connect/token", {
    method: "POST",
    body: JSON.stringify(formData)
})
```